# MYSQL SUM() the total score

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I have a simple jasper report which only have USER and SCORE as column and uses mysql ad the DB. Now the report works fine. But then I want to total the total SCORE and display it maybe at the bottom of the report. How can I do this? When I do a simple sum(SCORE) on the query, it gets the desired total but it will only return one row. I want to display all row and at the same time display its total SCORE. Can somebody help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use A JasperReports variable. You'd create a variable of type *Sum* with the variable expression *$F{score}*. Then you can drag it anywhere in the report, it appears as Text Field. If you don't put it in the summary band make sure that the *evaluation time* for the text field is set to *Report*.

There is no need to modify the query in order to achieve this.

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I am looking for! Thanks man, you save me some time :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use something like:

```
SELECT userId, SUM(score)
FROM userScores
GROUP BY userId WITH ROLLUP;
```

This would return a row of each user ID and their sum score, as well as a "rollup" row with `NULL` for `userId` and the total sum score.

See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html) for more info.